# knockout gives unable to parse binding attribute in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

**EDIT:** Answered myself, error was because of old version of knockout, always use newest version, and check existing!

i've been following knockouts tutorial, and tried to do something myself, but get the error, even when I basically have the same code.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks">
<li>
    <input data-bind="value: title" />
</li>
</ul>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            function Task(data) {
                this.title = ko.observable(data.contentName);
            }

            function TaskListViewModel() {
                // Data
                var self = this;
                self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

                // Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
                $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("GetContentList", "TranslateContentMenu") %>',
                    {
                        languageId: $('#LanguageIdNameValuePairs').val()
                    },  function (allData) {
                    var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Task(item) });
                    self.tasks(mappedTasks);
                });
            }

            var test = new TaskListViewModel();
            console.log(test);
            ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
        }())
</script>
```

The service i am calling, returns this result: 
[{"contentId":"1b07790c","contentName":"test"},{"contentId":"1b07790c","contentName":"test"},{"contentId":"1b07790c","contentName":"test"}]

and this is the error, straight out of firebug console: 
Error: Unable to parse binding attribute.
Message: ReferenceError: title is not defined;
Attribute value: value: title

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/wKEn4/. I think something wrong with html markup you didn't post. In what binding did you get an error?

Comment: I forgot the end ul tag in the code block, hence it wasnt included. I have attached the error message i get, for some reason, it seems that it doesnt understand that title is a Task object, and it fails, before the ajax request gets its response...

Comment: just fixed the error myself, it was due to old knockout version.... note to self: check version first!
Thanks alot for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get such error because at this time `tasks` array should be empty and knockout shouldn't generate `<li>` tag. Make sure that you are initializing `tasks` array with `[]` or with `nothing` not with something like this `[""]`.

Also you can try to initialize tasks with empty `Task` object:

```
self.tasks = ko.observableArray(new Task());
```

Comment: did that as well, i tried just about everything, except checking version number....
Thanks alot for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

The error i got was because i was using knockout 1.2.1, newest version as of today was 2.1.0, upgrading knockout made it work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Artem has pointed out in the comments this does work in the jsFiddle he constructed. The only thing I can put this down to is your badly formed HTML. You wrote:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks">
<li>
    <input data-bind="value: title" />
</li>
```

Knockout does not like badly formed HTML. You should try:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks">
<li>
    <input data-bind="value: title" />
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The missing ul was because i forgot to include it in the code block, unfortunatelly thats not the issue. It is a part of a bigger system however, so the fault may be somewhere else.

Comment: As you can see, the error was due to old version of knockout, so, my bad! 
Thanks alot for your time and help!